# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{T(n)}{2^{2^n}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, general-topology

Let $T(n)$ be the number of distinct topologies on a set with $n$ elements. Does $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle\frac{T(n)}{2^{2^n}}$ converge?

There is not much context to this unfortunately. It's a problem I came up with myself, when counting the number of topologies on an $n$-element set for $n=2,3$ (I am a beginner in topology). I am not sure of the difficulty of this problem but any progress toward a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Do you know an estimation for T(n)?

Comment: I didn't, but I suspected that would be the way forward, though it is very hard to estimate such a quantity.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: I agree with your comment as a rule, but this is a question of obvious interest that is obviously not homework.

Comment: @RobArthan When I commented, it's a PSQ.  Whether this is HW or not is [irrelevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778402/properties-of-nonnegative-orthant#comment5730427_2778402).

Comment: Not even diamond mod is immune to [CRUDE's deletion of PSQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2712921/290189). Hoping to help new uses and the answerer, I'm asking OP for more context so that it won't get deleted as a PSQ.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: What does PSQ mean? Whether or not the question is homework makes a very significant difference to my willingness to help.

Comment: @RobArthan You may refer to this [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/psq-and-the-faq) question for the meaning of PSQ, as well as [*How to ask HW questions*](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/290189) on [meta].  It's OK to ask HW questions here.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: Thank you for the pointer to explain your obscure MSE TLA. I know fine well that it is OK to ask homework questions on MSE, but my opinion on whether a question is homework makes a significant difference to my willingness to help if the OP has given limited evidence of their own work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes. From this paper: [The Number of Finite Topologies- D. Kleitman and B. Rothschild](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238867751_The_Number_of_Finite_Topologies), the authors show that $T(n)$ is like $O(2^{n^2/4})$.

Comment: With this fact that it's just the same as the number of preorders I suppose it doesn't require the full on analysis, as even with just binary relations there's only $2^{n^2}$.